# Error fix: raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : book1.adb:28 length check failed

Tags: ada

What I'm trying to do with Ada is to create a Book object and then print out that book. Problem is, the language is not very writable. When I compile, build the main file, and then execute the file, it gives me this error:

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : book1.adb:28 length check failed
```

Here's what I have in the body file:

```
package body Book1 is

function getAuthor (B: in Book) return AuthorName is

begin
  return B.getAuthor;
end getAuthor;

function getTitle (B: in Book) return TitleName is

begin
   return B.getTitle;
end getTitle;

function getNumberOfPages (B: in Book) return Pages is

begin
  return B.getNumberOfPages;
end getNumberOfPages;

function createBook (Author: in String; Title: in String; NumberOfPages: in Float)
                    return Book is
  B: Book;

begin
  B.getAuthor := Author;
  B.getTitle := Title;
  B.getNumberOfPages := NumberOfPages;
  return B;
end createBook;

end Book1;
```

Here's what I have in the spec file:

```
package Book1 is

type Book is tagged private;

subtype AuthorName is String (1 .. 300);
subtype TitleName is String (1 .. 750);
subtype Pages is Float range 0.0 .. 5000000.0;

function getAuthor(B: in Book) return AuthorName;

function getTitle(B: in Book) return TitleName;

function getNumberOfPages(B: in Book) return Pages;

function createBook(Author: in String; Title: in String; NumberOfPages: in Float)
                   return Book;

private
  type Book is tagged
     record
     getAuthor: AuthorName;
     getTitle: TitleName;
     getNumberOfPages: Pages;
   end record;

end Book1;
```

Here's what I have in the test file:

```
with Book1, Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Float_Text_IO;
use Book1, Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure testBook is

theRealBook: Book := createBook(Author => "Jordan White",
                                      Title => "The Last Christmas",
                                      NumberOfPages => 32.0);

procedure Print_Book (B: in Book'Class) is

begin
  Put (getAuthor (B => B));
  Put (getTitle (B => B));
  Put (getNumberOfPages (B => B));
  New_Line;
end Print_Book;

begin
Print_Book (theRealBook);

end testBook;
```

What exactly am I doing to get this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There *must* be a canonical answer to this question, but I can’t find it.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement here:

```
theRealBook: Book := createBook(Author => "Jordan White",
                                      Title => "The Last Christmas",
                                      NumberOfPages => 32.0);
```

Has an implicit length of strings for both author and title (String Literals).
This means that when you assign author and title here:

```
  B.getAuthor := Author;
  B.getTitle := Title;
```

You are making the assumption that "Jordan white" is a string of length 300. (Same problem for Title) 
I Suspect this is homework, so ill leave it up to you to figure out how to find the length, and bounds of strings, and how to assign array slices.